# Relative link to secure version of website

Tags: html, href

I have both a secure (`https://111.1.111.111`) and a unsecure (`http://111.1.111.111`) website with the same domain. On my unsecure homepage, I want to put a link to the secure version of the site. Currently I use an absolute link:

```
<a href="https://111.1.111.111">Please use the secure site</a>
```

However, I want to change this to a relative link so that if my ip or domain changes, the same code will still work. Is there anyway to relative link to the secure version of my site?

Comment: You would be better off using `.htaccess` or similar to automatically reroute to the secure website.

Comment: @Steve I currently need the unsecure version of the site for some other functionality. I guess I could just relative path a routing, however. I would prefer an easier plain html solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a "base url" as a variable, then use that variable throughout your site to create absolute links. For example, if you're using php:

```
<?php
$baseUrl = 'example.com'
?>
<a href="https://<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>">Secure site</a>
```

Then you could just use the $baseUrl throughout your site, and if you ever change the domain or ip address, you only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest another way is to have a common controller method which is responsible for redirecting to secure site.

Eg.

```
<a href="/secure?target=payment">Please use the secure site for payments</a>
```

you could identify the destination with some query parameters where necessary.